# Задержка при обработке события keyDown

Tags: события, javascript

**Доброго времени!**

Собственно, вопрос заключается в специфике обработки события keyDown в JavaScript.
Допустим, есть такой код:

```
...
function move(event)
{
    if(event.keyCode==37) x--;  // стрелка влево
    if(event.keyCode==39) x++;  // стрелка вправо
    }

$(function(){

...
window.addEventListener('keydown', move, false);
...

    });
    ...
```

Если удерживать одну из клавиш стрелок, то происходит задержка обработки события ровно в одну секунду, а если постоянно "тыкать" по клавише, то этой задержки нет. Собственно, почему так? И можно ли этого избежать? **Спасибо.**

Comment: я только так придумал: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/V6WmL/ был бы рад  узнать о лучшем решении.

Comment: Мне нравится ваше решение, @eicto. Оно просто и логично. Спасибо!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V6WmL/1/